# CANCELing a YARN step in EMR

Tags: hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have a long running YARN application running on EMR cluster.
Based on [Canceling EMR Steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cancel-emr-step/), the running steps  can be canceled with command
`aws emr cancel-steps` as long as Amazon EMR versions 5.28.0 and later is being used (which is the case for me), however when I issue the above against my running step it never kills the actual yarn application.
I can see the step changing it's status to **Canceled** in the UI, however if I ssh into the EMR and execute
`yarn application -list` I still can swe my application alive and well :)
In the logs I see

```
INFO waitProcessCompletion ended with exit code 137 : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
INFO total process run time: 344 seconds
2020-12-30T23:13:42.362Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2020-12-30T23:13:42.362Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 137 and took 344 seconds
```

Which, based on my understanding, means that the container did receive the SIGKILL command.
Can  someone advise why it is still not killing the application?

P.S I am using the **TERMINATE_PROCESS** cancelation option when executing the **cancel-steps** command.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One aspect that you might want to look at is the **cluster vs client mode of submitting the step.**
If you are using cluster mode, you can't kill that step through AWS SDK since it has no control of the actual yarn application, for this to work **you need to run your steps in the client mode.**

Please also check other implications of running in cluster vs client mode, if you are doing this for development then it is fine to use client mode.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I was hoping that there was some implementation for the SDK to do this, but I ended up writing a shell script and pass that as a step to kill the application. Cant do a client mode though as this is a prod application.